# Enable Developer item in Settings Menu of iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, crashlytics

I sent the build via Crashlytics to my customer, but he can't instal it (I added the UDID of his device to provision profile). I think, that the problem is because he didn't setup his device for development (because my build is developempent, not production).

For example when I open in my iPhone Settings and scroll down I see Developer string:

[image]

But my customer doesn't see this string in his iPhone. How can he enable this menu item? (he doesn't have app macbook, so he can't enable it with xCode)

Comment: Nope, that's not the issue.

Comment: why, I can't send build to the customer. The issue is that I need to enable iPhone for development without xCode. If it's impossible that's ok, but I just want to know that. I think that will be useful for other developers too

Comment: This statement is probably not true: "I added his device to provision profile".

Comment: Changed it in description, thank you

Comment: That wasn't my meaning.  The issue is that once you've added it to the provisioning profile you need to ensure you download a fresh copy of the PP and build against it.

Comment: I checked it 5 times, everything is OK with provision profile

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know much time has passed since the question was posted, but it appeared still actual for me. Posting the answer for XCode 9 that I have checked.
So to enable Developer item in settings on iPhone follow the steps:

1. Download and install Xcode on your Mac.
2. Open Xcode on your Mac.
3. Plug your iPhone into your computer.
4. Open your iPhone's Settings app.
5. Scroll down and tap Developer.